# Pull each user's "Member Of" security group list from a text file

Tags: powershell, loops

I written the below PowerShell script to pull the list security for each user. All user list are inside the text file "ulist.txt" line by line. It not pull some user from that text file where as that really exist inside the directory.

```
Clear-Host
$ul = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\ulist.txt"

ForEach ($item in $ul){
$item = $item.toupper()
Write-Host ------------------------------------------------------------------ -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host The user $item belongs to following security groups. -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host ------------------------------------------------------------------ -ForegroundColor Yellow
$allgroups = Get-ADUser $item -Properties *  | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select-Object name | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim("`r","`n") } 
$allgroups
Write-Host ------------------------------------------------------------------ -ForegroundColor Yellow 
}
```

Error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: xxxxxxxx
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. 
             The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
```

I do not understand what is wrong in this script.

It only pull and showing only the default group "Domain Users" for some users not the other groups associated.

Comment: When posting questions, please format them so that it's readable. And don't post same text more than once

Comment: Rather than piping to `Format-Table` and then `Out-String` and all of that, just change your `Select-Object` to `Select-Object -Expand Name` and end that line there. As for getting groups, each user lists what groups they belong to in the MemberOf property. That lists the DistinguishedName for the group, so if you want the friendly name you could do: `Get-ADUser $item -prop MemberOf |% MemberOf | Get-ADGroup |% Name`

Comment: @James Z   - I will follow that next time when I will post any new question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After modified a little bit when it was pulled and appended the user list, I did a little bit mistake. Instead of "select Name", I changed it to "select SamAccountName". Perfect, it displayed me what I was expecting.

Thank you Team.